# Backpack hiking poles loops

Tags: backpacking

Anyone knows where I can buy this piece for attaching the hiking poles to the backpack? Including the plastic "hook", not only the elastic band.

[image]

Comment: The elastic is easy ("shock cord" from a good camping shop or online), so the hard part is the hook with built-in adjuster

Comment: Its easy to find hooks, and adjusters but finding the piece that combines both is difficult

Comment: exactly.  It would be possible to use a separate hook and adjuster, but I don't have a suitable hook in my box of that sort of thing.  I'll show a couple of alternative methods

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the part you've shown is specific to one manufacturer, but direct equivalents might exist.  However they'd be hard to find.

Here are a couple of similar systems I've seen.

This one is from a LowePro camera backpack, used to carry a tripod.  That's similar in terms of attachment to trekking poles, but a fair bit heavier.  It uses a separate clip and adjuster.

[image]

and removed from the bag:

[image]

This gives you the quick release of the clip, while using the adjuster to set the length/tension.  The adjuster is merely the spring type, and needs to be quite a decent one to have enough holding force.  But it works well.  You could substitute other forms of cord adjuster.

For this second idea, I didn't have the original to hand, so I've mocked it up (using a shoelace instead of shock cord).  Note that it loops through the mating strap twice, to make it less likely to fall off.

[image]

Again, off the bag (double loop not shown):

[image]

This approach uses the adjuster itself rather like the toggle buttons on a duffel coat.  It's secure so long as the tension is maintained, but additionally requires the right shape of spring adjuster so the loop  hooks securely over it.

Neither of these is a direct replacement, but will get you going far more quickly than tracking down the closest adjustable hook.

Comment: Someone on Reddit recommend these https://www.gossamergear.com/products/lightrek-pack-bungee-attachment

Comment: Unfortunately it's too expensive to ship it to europe

Comment: You might want to see if you think the Nite-Ize CamJam would help.  That's available from UK suppliers at least, and quite likely in other countries too.

Comment: @jagjordi [extremtextil.de](https://www.extremtextil.de/en/components/cord-locks.html?p=1&n=60) is a good supplier for these kinds of things shipping in the EU. I couldn't find that particular design, though.

Comment: Finding the term "shock cord" has certainly helped me, any idea on finding those adjusters?  I haven't found anything that looks as good as those.